# Confused by CORS: Same page, same API controller, same style code, different results

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm creating a AspNet Web API application and an AspNet MVC application with KnockOut & JQuery in the UI, and I'm having difficulty getting the communication settings correct. I've installed the CORS package into the Web API. Currently both are running in localhost, and I'm debugging with Chrome.

One page in particular demonstrates the issues.  On that page I have a view model that contains two different but structurally identical functions.  Both call different but structurally identical API endpoints on the same Web API controller. The first function, loadNewBusiness, works without any special CORS configuration on the server.  The second generates a

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:53130/api/transation/getEndorsement/?id=277. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 

Header:
http://localhost:54708' is therefore not allowed access.
Request URL:http://localhost:53130/api/transation/getEndorsement/?id=277
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:*/*
Origin:http://localhost:54708
Referer:http://localhost:54708/Home/Transactions?PolicyId=118
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:D7A23CC9-F076-48A3-A98A-9D92FEFFB3EE
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
id:277
```

But the working call and the non-working call hit the same Web API controller with similar code. The first call (newBusiness) works, the second (endorsement) doesnt.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/transaction")]
    public class TransactionController : ApiController
    {
        private ICommandBus _commandBus;
        public TransactionController(ICommandBus bus)
        {
            _commandBus = bus;
        }

        [Route("getNewBusiness")]
        [HttpGet]
        public NewBusinessData getNewBusiness(int id)
        {
            var data = new GetNewBusinessParameters { Id = id };
            var result = (ICommandResult<NewBusinessData>)_commandBus.Submit<GetNewBusinessParameters>(data);
            return result.Result;

        }

        [Route("getEndorsement")]
        [HttpGet]
        public EndorsementData getEndorsement(int id)
        {
            var data = new GetEndorsementParameters { Id = id };
            var result = (ICommandResult<EndorsementData>)_commandBus.Submit<GetEndorsementParameters>(data);
            return result.Result;

        }
...
```

CORS configuration added to WebApiConfig.cs when package was installed

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

Finally, the JQuery Ajax calls.  The first works (newBusiness), the second (endorsement) doesn't.

```
self.loadNewBusiness = function (id) {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        var rdata = {
            id: id
        };
        var xhr = $.get('http://localhost:53130/api/transaction/getNewBusiness/', rdata);
        xhr.done(function (data) {
            self.Id(id);
            self.EffectiveDate(data.EffectiveDate);
            self.BinderIssueDate(data.BinderIssueDate);
            self.BinderExpirationDate(data.BinderExpirationDate);
            self.RetroDate(data.RetroDate);
            self.TailExpirationDate(data.TailExpirationDate);
        });
        return d;
    };

    self.loadEndorsement = function (id) {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        var rdata = {
            id: id
        };
        var xhr = $.get('http://localhost:53130/api/transation/getEndorsement/', rdata);
        xhr.done(function (data) {
            self.Id(id);
            self.EndorsementType(data.EndorsementType);
            self.EffectiveDate(data.EffectiveDate);
            self.Premium(data.Premium);
            self.Description(data.Description);
            self.Text1(data.Text1);
            self.Text2(data.Text2);
            self.Money1(data.Money1);
            self.Money2(data.Money2);
            self.Date1(data.Date1);
            self.Date2(data.Date2);
        });
        return d;
    };
```

What am I missing?  How can two functions that are basically the same behave differently?

Comment: You can always test using a URL tester (like PostMan) which doesn't care about CORS, which is a very effective way to make sure the url works regardless of source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was NOT a CORS error in spite of the error message.  This was a simple spelling issue with the url.  The bad url had the word "transaction" misspelled.  Internet Explorer raised the correct error (404), so if you are in a similar situation, 1) don't trust the error messages and 2) try debugging with a different browser. I still prefer Chrome, but IE was better in this case.